# Reversing the CNF conversion after MAXSAT solve

Tags: sat, cnf

I have a boolean expression and wish to find valid values that maximize the number of true variables. Typical MAXSAT problem. The original expression is not in CNF form, so I used a converter. The conversion to CNF introduces many new variables. After solving the problem in CNF form, I need to get back to my original variable values to apply the solution.

I first generated the expression to be maximized. It's not relevant to this discussion but it comes from a geometry problem. The original input expression looks something like this:

( v3 & !v0 )
& ( v2 & !v0 )
& ( v1 & !v0 )
& ( v6 & v17 & !v0 )
...

Where there are some number of variables denoted v0, v1, etc.

I used limboole to convert this expression into a cnf formated file.

limboole.exe -d expressionfilename.txt

The output of which looks like...

c 1 v3
c 2 v0
c 5 v2
c 8 v1
c 11 v6
c 12 v17
c 16 v5
c 20 v7
c 21 v13
c 28 v9
c 35 v15
c 36 v19
c 40 v11
c 41 v18
c 48 v10
c 49 v14
c 380 v4
c 388 v16
c 395 v12
c 402 v8
p cnf 1559 4598
3 2 0
-3 -2 0
-4 1 0
-4 3 0
4 -1 -3 0
...
...

I then used sat4j to find an optimal solution for the cnf file, which looks like...

v -1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 -7 -8 -9 10 11 -12 -13 -14 ... ...

and has 1559 values, as it should.

My question is, now that I have a solution to the post-cnf conversion form, how do I relate those values back to my original v0,v1... variables? thanks for the help!

Comment: sorry I'm new here.. the new lines were taken out of my original post. In the cnf file, look for "p cnf 1559 4598". That's its own line which shows the number of new variables (1559) and number of clauses (4598) in the cnf representation. thanks!

Comment: It depends on how the variables are mapped, which depends on how "limboole" does that specifically (does it document that?). It would be trivial if you did the transformation yourself (I mean with your own code, doing it by hand would be silly) for example you could simply leave your original variables numbers the same, and then for variables introduced by the Tseitin transformation use variables with a higher number than the highest you had before.

Comment: By the way MAX-SAT means maximizing the number of true clauses, not the number of true variables (and if it *did* mean that then it would probably be meaningless to apply it to a formula with new variables that were introduced by such transformation)

Comment: You can search for a solution that maximizes the total weight of a set of variables you care about (ie ignoring variables introduced by Tseitin transformation) by making a counting circuit and asserting that the weight must be at least `k`, then binary search for the highest `k` that doesn't result in UNSAT

Comment: Thanks harold, each gave me good insights. It looks like the top of the cnf file (output of limboole.exe) says that my "v3" is the same as the new "1" etc. So I can just look through the output for my mapped vars to see what the solution said. I did not know max-sat was by clause. I will look in to putting weight on my variables, hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: SAT4J has some pseudo-boolean capabilities that may be useful for that, it even has a Knapsack example